# Specifying an http proxy with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

How do I specify a http proxy to use when running a spring-boot fat war as a tomcat server?

I have tried the following which is not working.

```
java -jar my-application.war --http.proxyHost=localhost --http.proxyPort=3128 --https.proxyHost=localhost --https.proxyPort=3128
```

and

```
java -jar my-application.war -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
```

Comment: I haven't tried this so I'm not making it an answer, but try

`java -jar my-application.war -Dhttp.proxyHost localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128`

Comment: that does not work either.

Comment: From Spring Boot Documentation, it looks like you need to make sure your proxy server is adding the `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers, or customize your embedded Tomcat server by specifying the `server.tomcat.remote-ip-header` and `server.tomcat.protocol-header` settings.  Also, make sure you have `server.use-forward-headers=true` in `application.properties`.  From https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server

Comment: @dspies not sure I understand.  I remember seeing these in the documentation but they don't appear to follow the traditional mechanics of specifying a proxy `host, port, {username, password}`. I have no control over the proxy server so can't configure custom headers.  How would I use the above given my proxy is running on `http://localhost:3128`

Answer (score 12):

I've found that I need -Dhttps.proxySet=true in order for the proxy config to actually be used.

Answer (score 10):

Put the JVM options before `-jar`. This should work:

`java -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -jar my-application.war`

**Explanation**

According to [java command-line documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), the command's syntax is:

`java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ arguments ]`

The `arguments` are the `args` that'll be received in your `main(String[] args)`. So, it's totally your responsibility to use them somehow. And if you forward them to spring using `SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);`, then you need to find documentation that says how spring uses `args` in the `run` method.

The `options`, however, are not sent to your app. One of their uses is to set what java calls `system properties` using `-Dproperty=value`. According to [Java Networking and Proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html), setting, e.g., `http.proxyHost` property makes the JVM proxy all your http request through that host.

Answer (score 2):

You may configure all property of REMOTE DEVTOOLS (RemoteDevToolsProperties) in application.properties.

```
spring.devtools.remote.context-path=  # Context path used to handle the remote connection.
spring.devtools.remote.proxy.host= # The host of the proxy to use to connect to the remote application.
spring.devtools.remote.proxy.port= # The port of the proxy to use to connect to the remote application.
spring.devtools.remote.restart.enabled=true # Whether to enable remote restart.
spring.devtools.remote.secret= # A shared secret required to establish a connection (required to enable remote support).  
spring.devtools.remote.secret-header-name=X-AUTH-TOKEN # HTTP header used to transfer the shared secret.
```

Answer (score 0):

need to add for authenticating proxy server

```
-Dhttp.proxyUser=**username**
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=**password**
```