# Unable to access rest point deployed on other server from spring boot executable jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, angular7, executable-jar

I have Angular application runs locally on localhost:4200 and access the rest points deployed on https://abc.xyz:20000.

I have put this entry in proxy.conf.json and update npm start command in package.json to

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

Locally angular application working fine.

I have packaged the angular application as executable jar using spring boot.

Now I have the executable jar name hello-world.jar.
It is started on spring boot embedded tomcat server at localhost:8080.

```
java -jar hello-world.jar
```

I am getting 404 error in chorme developer network tab while hitting rest points hosted on https://abc.xyz:20000.

It is due to jar doesn't know about the proxy configuration.

How should I configure the jar with proxy configuration that angular know with npm start.

I have tried this solution but this doesn't worked for me.

[Specifying an http proxy with spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951240/specifying-an-http-proxy-with-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

After too much struggle I am able to find out the solution. I was unable to consume the rest services due to CORS issue.

I have find solution for both rest services developed in Spring boot and JAX-RS.

**Rest Services in Spring Boot:**
In Controller : Configure CORS

```
@CrossOrigin(value='*', maxAge='3600')
@RestController
```

**Rest Services in JAX-RS**
Add the filter i.e. CORSFilter.java

```
package com.learn.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class CORSFilter implements Filter  {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        // Authorize (allow) all domains to consume the content
        ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, POST");


        // pass the request along the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}
```

Add Entry in **web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.learn.filter.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```