# could anyone tell me how to set http proxy in embedded tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-proxy, embedded-tomcat-8

I tried to use `-Dhttp.proxyHost` properties as jvm option to boot spring-boot web application， but it is useless。

here is my code：

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 -Djava.ext.dirs=d:\test\MyApp\WEB-INF\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\ext MyApplication
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Can you provide more information about your error ?

Comment: @bsc2xp this will help [spring-boot-behind-a-network-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168113/spring-boot-behind-a-network-proxy)

Comment: this also helps [specifying-an-http-proxy-with-spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951240/specifying-an-http-proxy-with-spring-boot/46581166)

Comment: Try : `java -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888 -jar MyApplication`

Comment: thanks very much。I made a mistake.https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Observe-Traffic/Troubleshooting/NoTrafficToLocalhost